# Hibernate jpa does honour AttributeConveter

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ejb-3.1

I have defined an attribute converter like this:

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class MyConverter implements AttributeConverter<MyType, String> {

    @Override
    @Nullable
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(@Nullable final MyType attribute) {
        LOG.log(Level.INFO, "Converting '{'{0}'}' to DB column", attribute);

        return attribute != null ? map(attribute) : null;
    }

    @Override
    @Nullable
    public MyType convertToEntityAttribute(@Nullable final String dbData) {
        LOG.log(Level.INFO, "Converting '{'{0}'}' to type", dbData);

        return dbData != null ? map(dbData) : null;
    }

}
```

Then in my entity class:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {
  @Id
  private Long id;
  private MyType myData;
}
```

According to jpa2.1 specs, i do not have to annotate the attribute field with @Convert if i have specified autoApply on the converter.
Nonetheless, even if i do not specify the autoApply on the converter and specify the following:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {
  @Id
  private Long id;
  @Convert(converter = MyConverter.class)
  private MyType myData;
}
```

Hibernate still does not consider this converter.

What could i be doing wrong?
I have deleted the table and regenerated it, but nothing does help.

I have tried hibernate versions from 4.3.4 - 4.3.8 with no success, n wildfly 8.1

As aside note, My converter is declared in an entity-jar, which is then included in ejb-jar as a dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.

After several hours, the solution seems to be simple.
My mistake was that i declared classes in the ejb-jars persistence.xml, instead of specifying the jar-file element. Therefore, the jpa hibernate annotation engine had no idea of my entity-jar, and could not scan it for the Converter annotation